# Jquery post method Call

Tags: jquery, post

Could somebody please advise how to call post method on load?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.getParams.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var param1 = $.getURLParam("userID");
  var param2 = $.getURLParam("password");
  alert(param1);

$.post("xlogin.php", { eid: param1 , pw:param2  });

});
</script>



</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I  want to call this post operation on load of the above PHP code . But some thing is missing ..

Comment: During the load of after the document is ready? Because $(document).ready() means that the function is executed right after the document is ready. And what do you mean by "something is missing"? It doesn't execute, or are there any errors?

Comment: That's the most bizarre login I've ever seen, are you using a GET to post login credentials!?

Comment: thanks  Briedis , Iam OK after the document is loaded and "some thing missing" is the "Post" method is not getting executed ... AM I missing any code ..?

Comment: Thanks cusimar9 , This is such a case for us to show demos to the clients . They want Single sign on to all the applications , But they are OK even if we show it like this and later we can implement real SSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing any callback to `$.post`, so even though `xlogin.php` is getting a POST request, you're not doing anything with the result.

To do something after the post request, you need do something like this (just an example):

```
$.post("xlogin.php", { eid: param1 , pw:param2  }, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        window.location = '/loggedIn/';
    }
    else {
      alert('Login failed');
    }
});
```

This example assumes `xlogin.php` returns a JSON document with a `success` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot infinity for the code . I tried even else condition , both are not getting called . $.post("xlogin.php", { eid: param1 , pw:param2  }, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        window.location = '/loggedIn/';
    }
    else {
     window.location = '/Logout/';
    }
});